# $L^2$ norm of the derivative of the density function of $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^{2})$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, normal-distribution, density-function

I have difficulty with the following calculation : $\lVert f'\rVert_{L^2}^{2}$ with $f(x)=\frac{1}{(2\pi\sigma^{2})^{1/2}}e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}$

We have $f'(x)=\frac{-(x-\mu)}{(2\pi)^{1/2}\sigma^{3}}e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}$

Then $(f'(x))^{2}=\frac{(x-\mu)^{2}}{2\pi\sigma^{6}}e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^{2}}{\sigma^{2}}}$

$\lVert f'\rVert_{L^2}^{2}=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(f'(x))^{2}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{(x-\mu)^{2}}{2\pi\sigma^{6}}e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^{2}}{\sigma^{2}}}dx=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^{6}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(x-\mu)^{2}e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^{2}}{\sigma^{2}}}dx=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^{6}}\frac{(\sigma^{2}\pi)^{1/2}}{(\sigma^{2}\pi)^{1/2}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(x-\mu)^{2}e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^{2}}{\sigma^{2}}}dx=\frac{1}{2(\pi)^{1/2}\sigma^{5}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(x-\mu)^{2}\frac{e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^{2}}{\sigma^{2}}}}{(\sigma^{2}\pi)^{1/2}}dx$

where the last integral corresponds to the variance of $\mathcal{N}\left(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)$ thus we have

$\lVert f'\rVert_{L^2}^{2}=\frac{1}{4(\pi)^{1/2}\sigma^{3}}$

Is this seems correct ?

Thank you a lot !

Thank you to Lukas for his help !

Comment: The integral in the end is not exactly the variance of $\mathcal N(\mu, \frac{\sigma^2}{2})$ because for the integrand to be the density of that normal distribution we are missing the factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \frac{\sigma^2}{2}}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{ \pi} \sigma}$ which will give the result $\lVert f'\rVert_{L^2}^2 = \frac{1}{4 \sqrt{\pi} \sigma^3}$ in the end.

Comment: Thank you a lot you are totally right !